# Flash embed with html overlay, wmode="direct"

Tags: html, flash, video, embed, overlay

I'm trying to place html elements over a flash video which **must be rendered with wmode="direct"** (video occupies entire window with html UI to be laid over it, anything other than direct makes CPU usage surge).

I've tried using an iframe to include the flash video, but I'm still unable to place any elements over it. Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. Until now I can see that the problem happen when you apply any Alpha color, like background opacity in this way:      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); When I set the 0.7 to 1 then it get on top of flash. (Only happen in Window)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Adobe's wmode browser support matrix](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_), all major browsers at current versions on Mac already support this use case.  On Windows support is spotty, only IE 9+ is claimed to work.

Like you, I'm trying to find out if/when Adobe plans to extend HTML overlay support for wmode=direct in Windows browsers.  The linked page only talks about Chrome up to 10 and FF up to 4, so more progress may have already been made since the doc was last updated.

If I find out something useful I'll add it to this answer, until then it's probably safest to assume you need IE 9+ on Windows to support direct+overlay.

Answer (score 1):

We are finding that most browsers support HTML overlay when `wmode="direct"` - however no browser is able to support transparency overlayed on top of the flash. Not even PNGs can alpha blend correctly. Any pixels that have an alpha channel and ignore as if there was no pixel at all.

When creating UI to layer over the top of flashs we have to "blanket out" the SWF - or - use rectangular DOM elements (ie, no rounded corners)

Furthermore - IE 9 on Windows 7 and older version simply fail to overlay *anything* over the flash. Iframes seem to pierce the SWF, but HTML elements do not.